# Layout no render on some actions in Zend Expressive?

Tags: php, layout, mezzio

Is it possible to set layout no render in one Action (or set of Actions)?

As I know I can set default layout in config, 
which will render on every page. 
I can change it in Action bay passing the 'layout' variable with value, 
but is it possible to not render layout at all?

```
class IndexAction
{
    private $template;

    public function __construct(Template $template){ ... }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next = null)
    {
        if(!$request->hasHeader('X-Requested-With')){
            $data = ['layout' => 'new\layout']; //change default layout to new one
        }
        else{
            $data = ['layout' => false]; //I need only to return view ?
        }

        return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render(
            'web::index', $data
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to return json data there is also the `Zend\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse`. You use it like this: `return new JsonResponse($dataArray);`

Comment: Thanks! But I need to return HTML. In first request (without ajax) need to return Layout + View and if it's ajax request to return only View because I don't want to load layout again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's available, just set layout = false

```
    return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render(
        'web::index', 
        ['layout' => false]
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions and templates in Zend Expressive are one-to-one, so I think that the decision whether layout should be rendered or not should be made in the appropriate template itself. Basically, it's a matter of omitting `<?php $this->layout('layout::default'); ?>` from your action template.

In your particular example, that condition you have should result in choosing different template to be rendered (one that doesn't include layout), instead of a solution with sending a flag to the template. For example:

```
$templateName = $request->hasHeader('X-Requested-With') 
    ? 'template-without-layout' 
    : 'template-with-layout';

return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render($templateName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I use plain layout:

```
<?php

echo $this->content;
```

There is [PR](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-zendviewrenderer/pull/23) to disable layout rendering.